# passing latitude and longitude from javascript or html to Django view

Tags: javascript, django, geolocation, maps

How to pass lat and lng to Django view without button click

```
pos = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude,};
```

I am working on a Django project and trying to get the current location of the user. i have a javascript function that returns the latitude and longitude , but i cannot pass them to Django as variables to save them or to do anything with them. I am using google maps api.

Comment: Uhm, could you explain your question a bit better , like where are you getting the co-ordinates from? and if possible add some more details which you think would help us to understand your issue a bit more

Comment: Thanks for response, i am working on a django project and trying to get the current location of the user. i have a javascript function that returns the latitude and longitude , but i cannot pass them to django as variables to save them or to do anything with them. I am using google maps api.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Django view parameter to pass some data to your views : **

*views.py*

```
def coordinates(request, lat, long):
    // You may try to convert the lat and long variables
    // in the good type, i suppose here they are float
    my_lat, my_long = Float(lat), Float(long)
    context = {'lat': my_lat, 'long': my_long}
    
    return render(request, 'coordinates.html', context)
```

*urls.py*

```
from app_name import views

path('coordinates/<str:lat>/<str:long>/', views.coordinates, name='coordinates')
```

**NB :** I passe the lat and long here as string, but in the view i convert them with Float().
And this is an example of url: `http://localhost:8000/coordinates/3.45/4.57`

*.html*

```
<section>
    The latitude is : {{ lat }}
    <br>
    The longitude is : {{ long }}
</section>
```